# Problems Installing Python GTK+3 for Windows

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, gtk3, pygobject

I've been following the PyGObject installation instructions for Windows:
http://pygobject.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html#windows-logo-windows

However, the installation seems to freeze in the middle of the GTK+3 install. At first I thought a couple of the packages were taking a while to install. But after several attempts I'm confident the install is freezing.

Here is the command I have been using: `pacman -S mingw-w64-i686-gtk3 mingw-w64-i686-python2-gobject mingw-w64-i686-python3-gobject`

Once it begins installing the necessary packages (and dependencies) it generally freezes between the 3rd and 9th package in the list. It does not seem to freeze on a particular package, instead it completes the one its on and never begins installing the next.

**Below is an example of what I'm seeing (it will sit like this for hours, even days):**

```
resolving dependencies...
looking for conflicting packages...

Packages (26) mingw-w64-i686-atk-2.22.0-1  mingw-w64-i686-ca-certificates-20150426-2  mingw-w64-i686-gdbm-1.12-1
          mingw-w64-i686-gnome-common-3.18.0-1  mingw-w64-i686-gobject-introspection-runtime-1.50.0-1
          mingw-w64-i686-json-glib-1.2.2-1  mingw-w64-i686-libepoxy-1.3.1-1  mingw-w64-i686-libsystre-1.0.1-2
          mingw-w64-i686-libtasn1-4.9-1  mingw-w64-i686-libtre-git-r122.c2f5d13-4  mingw-w64-i686-ncurses-6.0.20161001-1
          mingw-w64-i686-openssl-1.0.2.j-1  mingw-w64-i686-p11-kit-0.23.2-2  mingw-w64-i686-pygobject-devel-3.22.0-1
          mingw-w64-i686-python2-2.7.12-1  mingw-w64-i686-python2-cairo-1.10.0-3  mingw-w64-i686-python3-3.5.2-2
          mingw-w64-i686-python3-cairo-1.10.0-6  mingw-w64-i686-readline-6.3.008-1  mingw-w64-i686-shared-mime-info-1.4-2
          mingw-w64-i686-tcl-8.6.6-1  mingw-w64-i686-termcap-1.3.1-2  mingw-w64-i686-tk-8.6.6-1  mingw-w64-i686-gtk3-3.22.1-1
          mingw-w64-i686-python2-gobject-3.22.0-1  mingw-w64-i686-python3-gobject-3.22.0-1

Total Installed Size:  312.08 MiB

:: Proceed with installation? [Y/n] y
(26/26) checking keys in keyring                                                 [#############################################] 100%
(26/26) checking package integrity                                               [#############################################] 100%
(26/26) loading package files                                                    [#############################################] 100%
(26/26) checking for file conflicts                                              [#############################################] 100%
(26/26) checking available disk space                                            [#############################################] 100%
:: Processing package changes...
( 1/26) installing mingw-w64-i686-gnome-common                                   [#############################################] 100%
( 2/26) installing mingw-w64-i686-atk                                            [#############################################] 100%
( 3/26) installing mingw-w64-i686-json-glib                                      [#############################################] 100%
( 4/26) installing mingw-w64-i686-libepoxy                                       [#############################################] 100%
( 5/26) installing mingw-w64-i686-shared-mime-info                               [#############################################] 100%
```

If anyone has any suggestions, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Thanks

Comment: Just tested out that command and it worked for me. [Here is a pastebin](https://pastebin.com/zsYt6XLM) of all of the dependencies it installed for me. I had to install a lot more dependencies (57) when I ran it, so it might be interesting to look at the differences.

Comment: @CodeSurgeon Thanks! I suspect my dependency list is much smaller in my example because I copied it after several attempts to install. Initially my first install attempt looked very similar to yours, however, it began to hang somewhere after the `:: Processing package changes...` output (somewhere between lines 105 and 111 in your Pastebin).

Comment: @CodeSurgeon Each time I try run the command, it begins the normal process. It begins installing dependencies and then just hangs at a random point in-between packages (the previous dependency always completes to 100%). I never get an error, but it seems to hang indefinitely. It's very strange.

Comment: That is pretty weird! I am honestly not too familiar with Msys2 or pacman, but I found [this page](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=690438) which mentioned the `pacman -Rs` command. This removes a package and recursively uninstalls its dependencies. If you tried installing multiple times, perhaps cleaning up and retrying would not be a bad idea. In your case, use `pacman -Rs mingw-w64-i686-gtk3 mingw-w64-i686-python2-gobject mingw-w64-i686-python3-gobject`. When I tried it, it only removed 39 of my packages though, but it did prevent me from running `gtk3-demo` until I reinstalled!